# Why am I getting this bug?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am editing an android program. 
I am getting the following error:

```
cannot find symbol variable layout
```

It is pointing a line of Java code

```
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

Layout is underlined. I am assuming that this is referencing my splash.xml file.That file is in the res/layout directory.

Here's the code in full:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Splash extends Activity
{

    private static int timer = 6000;                    //timer

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Intent x = new Intent(Splash.this, Main.class); //launching main
                startActivity(x);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, timer);
    }

}
```

Comment: click "rebuilt" on AndroidStudio

Comment: Or alternatively, delete `R.java` and re-build (it will be re-generated)

Comment: Post your activity pls

Comment: Try *File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart* and drop all caches

Comment: @PaulThompson You're assuming he's using IDEA, which might not be the case.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Are you sure your layout XML is correct?

Comment: I am using android studio.

Comment: @m0skit0, that's why it's a comment not an answer. muchschair, did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @Paul Thompson Yes I did with no avail. What I did try was Studio's suggestion of importing .R (which I don't have to do in other activities. My splash screen now runs but the program crashes before it gets to the main.java. Not sure if it is related.

Comment: If the original problem was solved, please post another question. Also I would recommend you to learn Java and go through the Android tutorials first.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Clean' and 'Rebuild' from the Build tab from your top menu section!
Sometimes the R.java doesnt register the changes and assign id to the newly created components!

Comment: @munchschair could you specify the actual purpose of the above mention code? what exactly are you trying to achieve?
Do you mant to jump from one activity to another?